# Space bar uneven after cleaning and older keyboard. How can I correct this?

Tags: keyboard

I've cleaned my keyboard ([Sharkoon Skiller Pro](https://en.sharkoon.com/product/SkillerPro)) today as it was a real major mess. But after putting every key back to its original place. The space bar struggles to click.

It's an older type, I've been trying to find something similar but nothing. It's a space bar with one long metal bar and two springs.

The springs look strange, I've been trying to place them to the side. Which what made them look weird but it only made the whole space bar harder to return. I've put the metal bar in reverse but there isn't any improvement on it. I've tried to put the metal bar in the keyboard first but this isn't that type of keyboard to hold it in place, only the key itself can do that. The metal bar isn't bend in any way.

The space bar itself works if you click in the middle, but now it's obnoxiously loud and doesn't sound right. But the moment you click on the very corners, it becomes uneven and unresponsive. The space bar itself it is somewhat hard to click at times, as if something is blocking.

Would appreciate some advices/tips on it... been working on it for 2 hours now with no luck.

[image: Uneven click on left and right]

[image: The inside of the keys]

Comment: The only keyboard I know like that is the very old IBM Keyboard that came with the first IBM Desktop computers. The keys had an overcenter action and if the springs do not go back correctly, the keys do not work. If this seems like what you have I do not know if it can be fixed

Comment: The stabilizers (that metal bar) on these kinds of keyboards are annoying to get back into place. These might help: https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/4j2ex3/i_tried_removing_my_keys_to_clean_my_keyboard_but/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cS8pYX_XFl4

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MC10 and the links provided.

I managed to get the stabilizer first on keyboard but I had to pull it backwards. Where the stabilizer should be laying on is somewhat unclear as it's too wide. But I made sure the shorter parts sit on top of the hooks of the plastic. The longer parts are somewhat under the plastic but slightly sticking out as mentioned before, it's a bit to wide.

[How I've placed it, for someone who needs it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkgwo.png)

It worked at first and it doesn't look anymore that uneven. But the more I've pressed it, the more it came back where it was at first. The sides of the spacebar doesn't work anymore.

I fear what John might have said is true. It has too much overcenter and due being an older model, it won't be as easy to fix. I could have added something to balance the keyboard on the sides, but due how tight it is now. I fear the keyboard won't able to spring back on it's own.

I've already ordered a new keyboard as I do type a lot but more on the sides of it, it will become too distracting eventually. I will give the keyboard to my father who likes to slam keyboards. As in this state, I do have to slam the spacebar to get it working.